# I'm trying to configure React Routes, but all I get is a white screen

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to configure `React Routes`, but all I get is a white screen (no error message).

This works just fine without the routes

```
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Services from './components/Services';
import About from './components/About';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import {Routes,Route} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
   return(
   <> 
<BrowserRouter>
<Navbar/>
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
  <Route exact path="/service" component={Services}/>
  <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
  <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
</Routes>
<Footer/>
</BrowserRouter>
</>
 );
 }

 export default App;
```

Comment: Can you try using element instead of components. Which version of react-router are you using?

Comment: Which version of react-router-dom are you using?

Comment: I got this error when I ran your code in a sandbox: "Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page." Try replacing "component" with "element".

Comment: Correct. Several breaking changes were introduced in v6. I am assuming the op is using v6 too.

Comment: I'm actually using v6, I tried element instead of component and it works!! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of React you might need to change "component" to "element", you can learn more about the react-router here as well, It should work now. https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/primary-components

```
import Home from './components/Home';
import Services from './components/Services';
import About from './components/About';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import {Routes,Route} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
   return (
   <> 
<BrowserRouter>
<Navbar/>
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/"  element={<Home/>}/>
  <Route exact path="/service" element={<Services/>}/>
  <Route exact path="/about"  element={<About/>}/>
  <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Contact/>}/>
</Routes>
<Footer/>
</BrowserRouter>
</>
 )}

export default App;
```

Comment: You included react router v5 link and it doesn't say anything about the element. Also you didn't change anything in the code you included here.

Comment: Yes, I am Sorry I just forget to render these into the element! As I said you will have to change it to an element instead of a component. So Now It should work I have made changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using v6, you should change "component" to "element", as written at documentation

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

This should work:

```
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Services from './components/Services';
import About from './components/About';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import {Routes,Route} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
   return(
   <> 
       <BrowserRouter>
       <Navbar/>
       <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />}/>
          <Route exact path="/service" element={<Services />}/>
          <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />}/>
          <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Contact />}/>
       </Routes>
       <Footer/>
       </BrowserRouter>
   </>
 );
}

 export default App;
```